# Transient gen_server processes and updating pids

Tags: multithreading, erlang, gen-server

I'm currently learning Erlang at a reasonable clip but have a question about gen_server with supervisors.  If a gen_server process crashes and is consequentially restarted by a supervisor, it receives a new pid.  Now, what if I want other processes to refer to that process by Pid?  What are some good idiomatic ways to 'update' the Pid in those processes?

As an exercise with some practical application, I'm writing a lock server where a client can request a lock with an arbitrary key.  I ideally would like to have a separate processes handle the locking and releasing of a particular lock, the idea being that I can use the timeout argument in gen_server to terminate the process if no one has requested it after N amount time, so that only currently relevant locks will stay in memory.  Now, I have a directory process which maps the lock name to the lock process.  When the lock process terminates, it deletes the lock from the directory.

My concern is how to handle the case where a client requests a lock while the lock process is in the middle of terminating.  It hasn't shutdown yet, so sniffing that the pid is alive won't work.  The lock process hasn't reached the clause that deletes it from the directory yet.

Is there a better way to handle this?

*EDIT*

There are two gen_servers currently: the 'directory' which maintains an ETS table from LockName -> Lock Process, and the 'lock servers' which are added dynamically to the supervision tree using start_child.  Ideally I would like each lock server to handle talking with the clients directly, but am worried about the scenario of a request to acquire/release getting issued with call or cast when the process is in the middle of crashing (and thus won't respond to the message).

Starting with {local} or {global} won't work since there can be N amount of them.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to name the process and don't refer to it by its pid. You generally have 3 viable options,

- Use registered names. This is what andreypopp suggests. You refer to the server by its registered name. *locally* registered names have to be atoms, which may somewhat limit you. *globally* registered names do not have this limitation, you can register any term.
- The Supervisor knows the Pid. Ask it. You will have to pass the Supervisor Pid to the process.
- Alternatively, use the gproc application (exists on http://github.com). It allows you to create a generic process registry - you could have done that by ETS, but steal good code rather than implement yourself.

The pid is usable if all processes are part of the same supervision tree. So the death of one of them means the death of the others. Thus, the Pids recycling doesn't matter.

Comment: "globally registered names do not have this limitation, you can register any term" Didn't know that, it may come in useful.

Comment: What about in cases where we are dynamically adding children to the supervision tree with start_child on the supervisor as in this case?  Registering to a local or global limits all functionality to one process, isn't that right?

Comment: I personally use gproc, so I can register any term in the gproc table. Then, identifying the process by this term is easy.

Comment: Hi, this is a late comment and I hope you will be notified. If I follow your technique with gproc, and say in a function I do 10 calls to a gen_server by it's name (like `{bus, BusId}`), it means 10 call to gproc, 10 ETS lookups. Is that ok ? Don't you think it is too much overhead ? To me it seems to be a perfect solution, but what about performance ?

Comment: forgot to tag you @IGIVECRAPANSWERS , please see my previous comment :)

Comment: You can often cache the Pid for the 10 calls. You will need some code handling the case where the Pid is gone anyway since there is no guarantee the process is there when you actually send a message to its inbox.

Answer (score 4):

Don't refer to gen_server process by pid.

You should provide API for your gen_server via `gen_server:call/2` or `gen_server:call/3` functions. They are accept `ServerRef` as first argument, which can be `Name | {Name,Node} | {global,GlobalName} | pid()`. So, you API would look like:

`lock(Key) ->
  gen_server:call(?MODULE, {lock, Key}).
release(Key) ->
  gen_server:call(?MODULE, {release, Key}).`

Note that this API is defined in the same module as your gen_server and I assume you starting you server with something like:


`gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], [])`

So your API methods can lookup server not by pid, but by server name, which is equal to `?MODULE`.

For more information, please see `gen_server` [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html).

Comment: Wouldn't this restrict me to one process only?  What about the case where I want to have multiple children procs?

Comment: Yes, it would. Hm... I thought you're using gen_server process for "directory" process, who manages locks handlers (maps its name to process, that handles lock). In that case you're also do not need to refer to any process by pid, "directory" process (which is our gen_server) is refered by its name, and lock handler access should be handled only via "directory" process's API (`lock/1`, `release/1`).

Comment: You are correct, the directory process is actually handled that way, registering to a local.  My API for the directory is handled as you suggest, since I only want one process anyway.  However, my lock processes are also gen_servers (so we have two), which get added dynamically through the supervisor using start_child.  Those are the ones I'm worried about since there can be any number of them, one per lock.

Comment: There are two ways I can think of:
  1) Your lock handlers should be as simple as possible:
``lock_handler(Key) -> receive release -> exit after ?LOCK_TIMEOUT -> release(Key) end.``.
  2) You should reregister lock handler in directory on reinitializing after failure using some internal API of directory server.

Comment: But, actually, I do not like the idea of having `gen_server` behavior for lock handlers, because gen_servers are registered processes and you will have an arbitrary amount of them — one for each key-lock. This will possibly introduce memory leak in your application, because atoms are not garbage collected (and you will register lock handlers with atoms as names).

Comment: Lock names are binaries in this case, since they'll eventually be requested over sockets.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely avoid the use of your "lock_server" process by using the "erlang:monitor/demonitor" API.

When a client requests a lock, you issue the lock.. and do a erlang:monitor on the client.. This will return you a Monitor Reference.. You can then store this Reference along with your lock.. The beauty of this is that your directory server WILL be notified when the client dies.. you could implement the TIMEOUT thing in the client.

Here is a snippet from code I had written recently..
https://github.com/xslogic/phoebus/blob/master/src/table_manager.erl

Basically, the table_manager is a process that issues lock on a particular table resource to client.. if the client dies, the table is returned to the pool..